# HTTPS gRPC request to asp.net server behind an Istio gateway fails

Tags: asp.net, .net, istio, istio-gateway, grpc-dotnet

I have a grpc asp.net server which is sitting behind istio ingress gateway. grpc request works while using TCP as gateway protocol but it fails if protocol is set to HTTPS. I am trying to use istio to terminate ssl/tls grpc request but no luck so far.

```
# working tcp gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: testing
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress # using istio ingress gateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 9093
        name: tcp-9093
        protocol: TCP
      hosts:
        - "mydomain.com"
```

```
# failing https gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: testing
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress # use istio ingress gateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 9093
        name: https-9093
        protocol: HTTPS
      hosts:
        - "mydomain.com"
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        credentialName: my_tls_cred_secret
```

Below is the response client is getting with https

```
StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset"
```

Below is the logs from istio ingress gateway controller

```
[2023-08-09T08:22:26.459Z] "POST /greet.Greeter/SayHello HTTP/2" 200 UR upstream_reset_before_response_started{remote_reset} - "-" 12 0 2 - "91.145.126.17" "grpc-dotnet/2.54.0 (.NET 7.0.9; CLR 7.0.9; net7.0; osx; x64)" "706488d1-1954-4dc5-a252-d1df34a23576" "mydomain.com:9093" "10.244.0.41:5001" outbound|5001||app-svc.testing.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.12:35426 10.244.0.12:9093 91.145.126.17:62974 mydomain.com -
```

versions:

- .net7
- Grpc.AspNetCore - 2.49.0
- kubernetes - 1.25.11
- istio - 1.17.2

Comment: And how the server log looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is because of the `:scheme` mismatch since original request is in **https** and istio terminates it to **http**. This mismatch is then detected by kestrel server in asp.net which rejects the request. To allow the request to go through `KestrelServerOptions.AllowAlternate = true` need to be set.

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddGrpc()

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.AllowAlternateSchemes = true;
});
```

Comment: Awesome!. I was stuck with this exact issue but didn't know about this workaround so I had to drop using grpc since I couldn't get it working with https. Could you please let me know how did you debug this issue or point me to an article that would explain the root cause of this issue.

Comment: I just read the documentation, had to deep dive to find this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.allowalternateschemes?view=aspnetcore-7.0